# How does Entity Framework find Down() methods when my code migrations are behind my database migrations?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Let's say I'm a developer and I check out an old version of the code, so that my local database is "ahead", like

```
local db migrations: A -> B -> C -> D
    code migrations: A -> B
```

How I fix this is by running

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration -B
```

in PCM. As I understand, that runs

```
D.Down()
C.Down()
```

But where does EF find those methods if they're not in the code I've checked out? Are they in the `[Model]` columns of `__MigrationHistory`? I thought that column only stored the model, not migrations.

Comment: The __MigrationHistory table contains a snapshot of the expected state of your database, I guess that, in absence of down migration to apply, it just apply the expected state of the defined migration, to your database.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that an old version of the code will know how to rollback the database. That information is held in the current version. You need to do `Update-Database -TargetMigration -B` using the current version *then* check out the old version.